# SSL connection error in shiny but not localy while using httr

Tags: r, ssl, shiny, httr

I am using R, version 3.3.1. My code for connecting and retrieving data from DATA API is:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
library(mongolite)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
    req <- list()
    for (i in 1:length(report_exe())) {
      reqOP <- rbind(fromJSON(toJSON(content(GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/v1/oibstatus/",
                                                 add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "59dd75a6525e"),
                                                 query = list(oib = report_exe()), httr::verbose()), type = "application/json"), null = "null"), flatten = TRUE))
      req[[i]] <- reqOP
    }
```

As you can see, I use `httr` package. If I run this code locally, inside shiny app it woks fine. But if I deploy it, and run it via shinyapp.io (https://forensis.shinyapps.io/Forensis/), it returns an error:

```
SSL connection error
```

Maybe the error is connected with fact that shinyapp.io uses Linux as os?